# CSS counter-reset does not work inside pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-counter

The following CSS counter example does not work as expected. The counter for sub-headings should reset after every main heading:

```css
body {
  font: smaller sans-serif;
  counter-reset: h1 h2;
}
h1:before {
  counter-reset: h2;
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
  counter-increment: h2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
```

However, the following works as expected:

```css
body {
  font: smaller sans-serif;
  counter-reset: h1 h2;
}
h1:before {
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
  counter-increment: h2;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
<h2>Sub-heading</h2>
```

My question is, why does `counter-reset` not work inside pseudo elements?

Comment: How very odd, I have just been messing around with this and cant find a reason. Also had a brief look at the documentation and cant see anything either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is a scope problem. The [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-counter-reset) state:

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in
>   a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new
>   instance of the counter....
>
> ... The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document
>   that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes the element's
>   descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.
>   However, it does not include any elements in the scope of a counter
>   with the same name created by a 'counter-reset' on a later sibling of
>   the element or by a later 'counter-reset' on the same element.

The way I understand this is that when you reset the counter a new instance of the counter is created on the parent element. If you do this on `h1:before` it gets created on that single `<h1>` element which is then immediately closed... hence you get no reset on the initial counter.

Comment: Correct, it took me a while to get my head around this (I have also been reading the documentation). So it acts as if the `<h1>` is the parent and starts a new counter instead of resetting the level up counter. +1

Comment: Yes, it didn't make it very clear at all. Just putting in this answer in that documentation would have saved us a lot of time!

Comment: To be fair, the spec caters to implementers more than authors. It's not meant to be author-friendly at all. Some of the level 3 and 4 modules are set to change this however.

Comment: Makes sense. But I don't get the part _"or by a later 'counter-reset' on the same element"_. How can you "later" reset a counter on the same element?

Comment: I think all they are saying is that once you've reset the counter on the same element, the previous counter no longer applies. So in other words, a reset on the same element is "out of scope" of the first counter.